# data-tab is not working properly in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 3 tabs in html page, if i click on 2nd tab then click back to 1st tab then it is slightly scrolling up, but if i do same thing from 3rd tab then it is working properly. and it happens only in IE.

```
<div>
  <div class="myTab">
   <button id="btn1"
    class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabFirst"></button>
   <button id="btn2"
   class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabSecond"></button>
   <button id="btn3"
   class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabThird"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.custom-tab').on('click',function(){
        someUpdateMethod($(this).attr("data-tab"));
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Brace yourself, downvotes are coming.... It is not possible for anyone to assist you if you do not include any code to review. Please see https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ Take a look at https://caniuse.com/ to see Browser compatibility of your css and javascript. Also are there any errors in the console? Are you sure that it only happens in IE?

Comment: Try this in other browsers and see what happens?

Comment: I guess data-tab attribute is your custom attribute, right? So whatever problem you have is inside your someUpdateMethod(). Show what you have inside that method. Probably you using some css that is not supported on IE or you using it wrong. From my experience I can say that Chrome and other browsers can "fix" little coding problems, and IE is very strict to parameters and properties.

Comment: it is working properly in other browser

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and one more thing **internet explorer** enable javascript.

```
    <div id="jsClickable">
      <div class="myTab">
       <button id="btn1"
        class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabFirst"></button>
       <button id="btn2"
       class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabSecond"></button>
       <button id="btn3"
       class="custom-tab" data-tab="tabThird"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jsClickable').on('click', '.custom-tab', function () {
        // someUpdateMethod($(this).attr("data-tab"));
          alert($(this).attr("data-tab"));
          alert($(this).data("tab"));
    })
});   
    </script>
```

Comment: @user  what you want `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`?

Answer (score 0):

window.scrollTo(0, 0); helps me to solve the problem

Comment: What you want `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` not working in browser?

Comment: dude actually when i was clicking on 1st tab then scroll was happening automatically and  window.scrollTo(0, 0); helps me to prevent that.

Comment: And you can use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Ok, so you want to prevent your scroll issues?

Answer (score 0):

Think that you should try: `$(this).data("tab")`